# Remove some characters from string

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm scraping some items of a site and get this as response:

```
<a href="t-1956883.html">Oh my gooood <span class="smalltext">403 readers</span></a>
```

Now I want to change the href from `t-1956883.html` to `http://www.somemagicsite.com/t1956883`.

This is my current RegEx that I got; `t-[0-9]*.html` but I don't know how I can filter out the results instead of just matching it.

Comment: What do you mean by filter out the results instead of just match, do you mean change that string in to the new one?

Comment: Yes, I want to alter the string I'm receiving before printing it out. I guess I'll use the preg_replace function but I haven't figured out the regex yet...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use This,

```
    $string = '<a href="t-1956883.html">Oh my gooood <span class="smalltext">403 readers</span></a>
';
    $pattern = '/t-(\d+).html/';
    $replacement = 'http://www.somemagicsite.com/t$1';
    echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
```

Check [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) in php.net

Comment: The last .html is still there. The url should be like this: http://www.somemagicsite.com/t1956883

Answer (score 0):

You can use [preg_replace function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) for this purpose.

```
echo preg_replace("t-[0-9]*.html",  "http://www.somemagicsite.com/t1956883", $string);
```

It should do the trick.